# How to make many independant/dependable select of elements?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input

Im trying to make ultimate code, that will find if the checkbox is checked and so after click it will enable the dependable block. That wasn't hard. But is it possible to make code work with the other alike elements without need to copy/paste code for each id or class. Here is the code: 
http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/GpmwaN

```
$('.main').click(function() {

    if ($(".dependable").is("[disabled]")) {
      $(".dependable").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $(".dependable").attr('disabled', 'true').removeAttr('checked');
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question, try this: [Demo](http://codepen.io/Turdiyev/pen/JYNxXJ)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[class^=main]').click(function() {

    var dep = $(this).closest('div').find("[class^=dependable]");
    if (dep.is("[disabled]")) {
      dep.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      dep.attr('disabled', 'true').removeAttr('checked');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Idea was correct, but what if these elements are over the document. See this [link](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/rOmoQa) to understand what I mean.

Comment: You should wrap both of them(`main` and `dependable`) at least for being dynamic. I don't see another dependence between of them(for example `id`, etc).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I will try.